# Ошибка при обновлении стейта React

Tags: reactjs

```
import style from "./login.module.css";
import logo from "../../../img/login__block/logo.svg"
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from "react";



class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
  tryLogin(event){

    event.preventDefault()

  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className={style.login}>
          <div className={style.login__logo}>
            <NavLink to={'/'}>
              <img src={logo}/>
            </NavLink>
          </div>
          <div className={style.login__form}>
            <div className={style.buttons__login__registration}>
              <button>
                Вход
              </button>
              <NavLink to={'/regestration'}>
                Регистрация
              </NavLink>
            </div>
            <form href="#">
              <label className={style.inputs}>
                <h2>
                  Логин
                </h2>
                <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text"
                      name="login"/>
              </label>
              <label className={style.inputs}>
                <h2>
                  Пароль
                </h2>
                <input type="text" name="login"/>

              </label>
              <label className={style.checkbox}>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                Запомнить
              </label>
              <label className={style.button_submit}>
                <button onClick={this.tryLogin} type="submit">
                  Войти
                </button>
              </label>
            </form>
            <div className={style.help_password}>
              <button>
                Забыли пароль?
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  };
}
```

Когда в текстовое поле ввожу текст, он туда не попадает

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')
    at handleChange (login.js:16:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
    export default Login;
```

Comment: Это не хук. Хуки в функциональных компонентах бывают

Comment: а как мне сделать двухстороннее связывание?